# Amount of ingredients for 3 boxes of cake mix

Tags: baking

When using 3 boxes of cake mix, do I triple the amounts of water eggs and oil to make cake batter

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For three boxes of mix you would triple the eggs, water and oil listed on one box.